# trouble programming UNIX redirects

Tags: c, unix, redirect, pipe

I am trying to simulate the redirects and pipe in unix (<, >, >>, |). i already manage to program all of them but the append (>>). Here is the peace of code where i check if the >> is in the cmd string.

```
   if(!strcmp(cmd[i], ">>")){
        aux[i] = NULL;
        fdW = open(cmd[i+1], O_APPEND);
        dup2(fdW, STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fdW);
    }
```

however when i call dup2() to redirect STDOUT to the opened file returns this error:

```
  cat: write error: Bad file descriptor
```

Does anyone know why this happens with O_APPEND and not with O_WRONLY.

Comment: Is fdW -1 ? Should the 2nd arg to open be `O_WRONLY|O_APPEND`?

Comment: to emulate `>>`: the 2nd arg could be `O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_APPEND`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian yes i see now what my problem was. i didnt know that i was supposed to use O_CREAT if i was using O_APPEND. Thank you for you answer.

Comment: This is why you *must* check all return values for error.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart true i learned my lesson

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't know I was required to use `O_WRONLY` even though I was using `O_APPEND`.